# Maven cannot run program "link"

Tags: c++, maven, maven-nar-plugin

I am trying to build a simple C++ project with maven and the nar-maven-plugin, but I'm getting the following error:

> Failed to execute goal
>   com.github.maven-nar:nar-maven-plugin:3.2.3:nar-validate
>   (default-nar-validate) on project it0015-cpp-executable: Could not
>   launch cmd.exe /X /C "link /?": Error while executing process. Cannot
>   run program "link": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the
>   file specified -> [Help 1]

I am using Windows 8.1. Does anyone have ideas on how to investigate this issue?

Comment: `link.exe` is part of Microsoft Visual Studio, which is what NAR typically uses under the hood to compile C++ code on Windows. Do you have MSVS installed? Are the executables on your path? Did you try running the Maven build from the MSVS command prompt instead of the vanilla command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

you should specify the linker you are using.

For me, i'm using MinGW so i update my user path (environment variable) with C:/MinGW/bin and in the nar-maven-plugin i specify the linker name to g++

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.maven-nar</groupId>
    <artifactId>nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
      <linker>
        <name>g++</name>
      </linker>
      <libraries>
        <library>
          <type>executable</type>
        </library>
      </libraries>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Now you can launch "mvn validate" to check if it works